# need to convert C++ template to C99 code

Tags: templates, cuda, opencl

I am porting CUDA code to OpenCL - CUDA allows C++ constructs like templates while OpenCL is strictly C99.  So, what is the most painless way of porting templatest to C?
I thought of using function pointers for the template parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately function pointers don't work on GPU's.  I'd agree with Roger and say that using the C preprocessor is the way to go.  Basically make your type variable a preprocessor token.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before there were templates, there were preprocessor macros.

Search the web for "generic programming in C" for inspiration.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the technique I used for conversion of some of CUDA algorithms from [Modern GPU](http://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/) code to my GPGPU [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) library (with OpenCL support).

Each template function in CUDA code is converted to two template functions in OpenCL host code. The first host function ('name' function) returns mangled name of the generated OpenCL function (so that functions with different template parameters have different names); the second host function ('source' function) returns the string representation of the generated OpenCL function source code. These functions are then used for generation of the main kernel code.

Take, for example, the [CTAMergeSort](https://github.com/NVlabs/moderngpu/blob/59e85339e71c94c6f41ae505623d0cc6b4826211/include/device/ctamerge.cuh#L179-L204) CUDA function template. It gets converted to the two overloads of [merge_sort](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/blob/50f27dcc1e3786ce3d9a827bb9fc3c42f8b868e0/vexcl/sort.hpp#L686-L737) function in VexCL code. I call the 'source' function in order to add the function definition to the OpenCL kernel source [here](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/blob/50f27dcc1e3786ce3d9a827bb9fc3c42f8b868e0/vexcl/sort.hpp#L838) and then use the 'name' function to add its call to the kernel [here](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/blob/50f27dcc1e3786ce3d9a827bb9fc3c42f8b868e0/vexcl/sort.hpp#L933-L943).

Note that the `backend::source_generator` in VexCL is used in order to generate either OpenCL or CUDA code transparently. In your case the code generation could be much simpler.

To make it all a bit more clear, here is the code that gets generated for the `mergesort<256,11,int,float>` template instance:

```
void mergesort_256_11_int_float
(
  int count,
  int tid,
  int * thread_keys0,
  local int * keys_shared0,
  float * thread_vals0,
  local float * vals_shared0
)
{
  if(11 * tid < count) odd_even_transpose_sort_11_int_float(thread_keys0, thread_vals0);
  thread_to_shared_11_int(thread_keys0, tid, keys_shared0);
  block_sort_loop_256_11_int_float(tid, count, keys_shared0, thread_vals0, vals_shared0);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am practically doing a C++ compiler job here. This could boggle an unprepared mind :).

Comment: this is f-ing awesome. It doesn't address my problem, but I would love to use this library at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute/). It provides a C++, STL-like API for OpenCL.

Comment: That looks awesome. Thank you for the pointer. However, it doesn't seem like it will help the OP in translating CUDA code with templates to OpenCL.